# Rake is aborting because undefined method `inet'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Where and how should I define `inet`? It's a valid postgreSQL data type.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-net-types.html

```
rake db:migrate
==  CreateSysHosts: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:sys_hosts)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x00000005e3e068>/opt/csdashboard/db/migrate/20140628123004_create_sys_hosts.rb:4:in `block in change'
```

Migration file:

```
class CreateSysHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sys_hosts do |t|
      t.inet :address
      t.string :name
      t.string :os_name
      t.string :os_flavor
      t.int :user_id
      t.string :info
      t.string :comments

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration file?

Comment: updated the question with migration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [postgres_ext](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem that supports enhanced datatypes of Postgres like inet.

An example [postgres_ext: Adding Postgres data types to Rails](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/06/18/postgres_ext-adding-postgres-data-types-to-active-record.html).

**postgres_ext** adds migration and schema.rb support for the following PostgresSQL type:

- INET
- CIDR
- MACADDR
- UUID
- Arrays

Comment: That will require upgrading from 3.2.14 to 4.x right?

Comment: I guess so. Or try an older version - https://rubygems.org/gems/postgres_ext/versions/1.0.0

Comment: Now I get undefined method `int' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x00000004c47698>/opt/csdashboard/db/migrate/20140628123004_create_sys_hosts.rb:9:in `block in change'

Comment: that should be a separate question though